# Paginate by most recent post with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I'm using the rails gem kaminari (https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) in order to paginate my posts database. Currently I have the code `@posts = Post.order('id').page(params[:page]).per(5)` in my controller, but this orders the pages from earliest to most recent. How do I reverse this and order from most recent to earliest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your model you can do:

```
default_scope order("created_at DESC")
```

or

```
default_scope order("created_at ASC")
```

Comment: I'd shorten the controller code to: `@posts =  Post.page(params[:page]).per(5)`

Comment: could i do, instead, `@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)` ?

Comment: Post.order('created_at DESC').page... is not working for me. It is sorting ascending.

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
    @all = Model.all
    @all = Model.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
end

def sort_column
    Model.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "updated_at"
end

def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "DESC/ASC"
end
```